# How can I access 'flight mode' in iphone4 without a sim card?

Tags: iphone

I am attempting to unlock an iPhone4. However, my issue seems to be that the phone doesn't recognize my SIM card. The advice I got from my previous carrier is to put the phone in 'flight mode'. This seems impossible to do without a working/recognized SIM card. Is there a short cut for accessing 'flight mode'?

Comment: What to do mean by unlock? Just getting past the unlock screen of the phone (which should be possible even without a SIM) or unlocking the SIM itself to make phone calls?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your iOS there are several options to do this.

One way is by jailbreaking the phone.
Using the iPhone IMEI and the Gavey SIM tool you should be able to unlock it.

use google to find out [more](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=unlock%20iphone%204%20without%20a%20sim%20card)